# Getting result from array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array look like this ,it is the result of a db select operation.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => shamonsha
            [username] => sham1s670
            [password] => 5hYZJPu3s/oAE7KbFfgsvQfX4/GCvnK1MpR0bIbWWxroUgLb+E3M7/AFyJNcZ9WirkAGCe6JBofh54dOPENdrg==
            [email] => shamonsha665@gmail.com
            [mobile_number] => 7736527089
            [address] => hk
            [date] => 24 Dec 2015 01:32:53
            [active] => 1
            [commission] => 25
            [agent_id] => 1
            [ticket_number] => ETS263B0PT10469
            [refund_amount] => 700
            [date_of_cancel] => 28-Jan-2016
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => shamonsha
            [username] => sham1s670
            [password] => 5hYZJPu3s/oAE7KbFfgsvQfX4/GCvnK1MpR0bIbWWxroUgLb+E3M7/AFyJNcZ9WirkAGCe6JBofh54dOPENdrg==
            [email] => shamonsha665@gmail.com
            [mobile_number] => 7736527089
            [address] => hk
            [date] => 24 Dec 2015 01:32:53
            [active] => 1
            [commission] => 25
            [agent_id] => 1
            [ticket_number] => ETS311B0PT10470
            [refund_amount] => 700
            [date_of_cancel] => 28-Jan-2016
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => shamonsha
            [username] => sham1s670
            [password] => 5hYZJPu3s/oAE7KbFfgsvQfX4/GCvnK1MpR0bIbWWxroUgLb+E3M7/AFyJNcZ9WirkAGCe6JBofh54dOPENdrg==
            [email] => shamonsha665@gmail.com
            [mobile_number] => 7736527089
            [address] => hk
            [date] => 24 Dec 2015 01:32:53
            [active] => 1
            [commission] => 25
            [agent_id] => 1
            [ticket_number] => ETS788B0PT10472
            [refund_amount] => 395
            [date_of_cancel] => 28-Jan-2016
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => shamonsha
            [username] => sham1s670
            [password] => 5hYZJPu3s/oAE7KbFfgsvQfX4/GCvnK1MpR0bIbWWxroUgLb+E3M7/AFyJNcZ9WirkAGCe6JBofh54dOPENdrg==
            [email] => shamonsha665@gmail.com
            [mobile_number] => 7736527089
            [address] => hk
            [date] => 24 Dec 2015 01:32:53
            [active] => 1
            [commission] => 25
            [agent_id] => 1
            [ticket_number] => ETS562B0PT10471
            [refund_amount] => 395
            [date_of_cancel] => 28-Jan-2016
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => shamonsha
            [username] => sham2s7b8
            [password] => dN0Br+3D86pGTAhlvOJ4OD6YH1KVHL/SkfYOu71Do7OCxrRnMIq9CLVWX7mpTnJso1pYxVwvjzFWo1a1GVq+8Q==
            [email] => shamonsha665@gmail.com
            [mobile_number] => 7736527089
            [address] => jk
            [date] => 24 Dec 2015 01:33:20
            [active] => 1
            [commission] => 0
            [agent_id] => 2
            [ticket_number] => ETS562B0PT10471
            [refund_amount] => 395
            [date_of_cancel] => 28-Jan-2016
        )

)
```

From this i want to display `ticket_amount`, `refund_amount` and `date_of_cancel` for each username like this way
Eg:

```
Username:sham1s670
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10469 ,refund-amount:700, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10461 ,refund-amount:500, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10462 ,refund-amount:200, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016

Username:sham1s674
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10462 ,refund-amount:700, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10468 ,refund-amount:600, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016
  ticket-no:ETS263B0PT10469 ,refund-amount:200, cancel-data:28-Jan-2016
```

Here is my tried code

```
$i=0;
foreach($result as $value)
{
    $old = $value['username'];
    if($old==$value['username'])
    {
        if($i==0){
            echo 'Username'.$value['username'];
            echo '<br>';
        }
        echo "TIcket-no".$value['ticket_number'].'Refund-amound'.$value['refund_amount'].'Cancel-date'.$value['date_of_cancel'];

        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
        $old='';
        $i=0;
    }
}
```

But it didn't give me the expected result?

Comment: What was the expected and the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not giving the desired result because $old will never be like $value['username'] (you never start that), hense always triggering else option.

You must either rewrite the query and group by user, or sort the results after they have been parsed to match user with tickets

Untested:

```
<?php

  $data = array();
  $output = false;

  // this first foreach could be done on db fetch rows instead
  foreach ( $result as $value ) {

      $data[$value['username']][] = 'TIcket-no ' . $value['ticket_number'] . ', Refund-amound ' . $value['refund_amount'] . ', Cancel-date ' . $value['date_of_cancel'];

  }

  foreach( $data as $username => $list ) {

    $output .= '<p>Username ' . $username . '<br>';
    $output .= implode( '<br>', $list );
    $output .= '</p>';

  }

  echo $output;

?>
```

** UPDATE PER REQUEST **

Add users name (still untested)

```
<?php

  $data = array();
  $output = false;

  // this first foreach could be done on db fetch rows instead
  foreach ( $result as $value ) {

      if ( !isset( $data[$value['username']]['name'] ) ) {
        $data[$value['username']]['name'] = $value['name'];
      }
      $data[$value['username']]['data'][] = 'TIcket-no ' . $value['ticket_number'] . ', Refund-amound ' . $value['refund_amount'] . ', Cancel-date ' . $value['date_of_cancel'];

  }

  foreach( $data as $username => $dataset ) {

    $output .= '<p>Name: ' . $dataset['name'] . '<br>';
    $output .= 'Username: ' . $username . '<br>';
    $output .= implode( '<br>', $dataset['data'] );
    $output .= '</p>';

  }

  echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Its worked,one more question i want result with `name` instead of username but the problem is same name may come for different usernames.

Comment: So how can i modify the above answer with name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested!), assuming you sort the result by username

```
$old='';
foreach($result as $value)
{
    if($old==$value['username'])
    {   
        echo "TIcket-no".$value['ticket_number'].'Refund-amound'.$value['refund_amount'].'Cancel-date'.$value['date_of_cancel'];

    }
    else
    {

        echo 'Username'.$value['username'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
    $old = $value['username'];
}
```

Comment: This is not working if all the usernames isn't sorted : user1, user2, user2, user1

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your results with a new array.

Like this :

```
<?php
$NewTab = array();
foreach($results as $val) {
    $NewTab[$val["username"]][] = $val;
}

foreach($NewTab as $username => $entries) {
    echo "Username:", $username;
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        echo "ticket-no: ", $entry["ticket_amount"];
        echo ", refund-amount: ", $entry["refund_amount"];
        echo ", date_of_cancel: ", $entry["date_of_cancel"];
    }
}
```